# How to raise Maclaurin expansion to -1 power?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

In a particular Maclaurin series exercise that had to do with finding the series expansion of $\sin(\ln(1+x))$ and $\cos(\ln(1+x))$ and hence $\tan(\ln(1+x))$, I came across the following step in a solution:

$\left(1-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+\frac{1}{2}x^{3}-\frac{5}{12}x^4+\,...\right)^{-1\ }=1+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}-\frac{1}{2}x^{3}+\,\,...$

How is that? The left-hand side is the expansion of $\cos(\ln(1+x))$. It looks like we are evaluating the series to a negative power... I don't know how to do that directly, and can't think of how to get around it. What am I missing?

(I know I could use $\sin(\ln(1+x)=\cos(\ln(1+x))\,\times\,\tan(\ln(1+x))$ to avoid this step via expanding and equating coefficients, but I want to know how the line above is evaluated.)

Comment: Substitute $-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+\frac{1}{2}x^{3}-\frac{5}{12}x^4+\ldots$ in place of $w$ in $\frac{1}{1+w}=1-w+w^2-w^3+\ldots$ and expand the right-hand side in powers of $x$. To get the 3 terms you are showing you only have to consider the geometric series up to the term $-w$. Another way is to put unknown coefficients on the right-hand side multiply through by the series on the left-hand side and equate the coefficients of $x^n$ $n\geq 1$ to $0$. In this way you get a system of equations for the unknown coefficients you are looking for.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Multiplication_and_division). Note that if you only need a few terms from the beginning, the coefficients are the same that you obtain by doing long division: $1$ divided by $1-x^2/2+x^3/2-\ldots$, but instead of dividing terms of largest degree, as with polynomials, you divide terms of lowest degree. Or even you can do long division directly of the series of $\sin(\ln(1+x))$ divided by the series of $\cos(\ln(1+x))$.

Comment: Yes, thanks for two nice methods, @Gary and plop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you want to comput the first coefficients of the Maclaurin expansion of$$\frac1{1-\frac12x^2+\frac12x^3-\frac5{12}x^4+\cdots}=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots.$$Note that\begin{align}1&=\left(1-\frac12x^2+\frac12x^3-\frac5{12}x^4+\cdots\right)(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots)\\&=a_0+a_1x+\left(a_2-\frac{a_0}2\right)x^2+\cdots\end{align}But then$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a_0=1\\a_1=0\\a_2-\frac{a_0}2=0.\end{array}\tag1\right.$$Solve the system $(1)$, and you'll have your answer.

Comment: Got it, thanks, @José

Comment: I'm glad I could help.